# List files that don't match a string in bash

Tags: bash, directory-listing

I'm a newbie in bash and I would like to pass as parameter to a python function all files in a directory that don't match a given pattern. sth. like:

$myscripts/myprog.py $myfiles/!(*bonjovi*)

The above example should retrieve all files that don't match to "bonjovi".

Best wishes

Answer (score 3):

You have the syntax exactly right. You just need to enable it.

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easiest to use `grep`, `xargs` and a regular expression. `grep -v` excludes lines (in this case filenames) matching a given pattern.

```
ls | grep -v 'bonjovi' | xargs myscripts/myprog.py
```

Comment: Great, thanks Charles! How could I also use regular expression for the grep parameter? let's say:
ls | grep -v '*bonjovi_album1*' | xargs myscripts/myprog.py
I made a small test, but "bonjovi_album1" is also retrieved in the output.

Comment: `*bonjovi_album1*` isn't a valid regular expression because there's nothing before the first `*`. `echo bonjovi_album1 | grep -v 'bonjovi_album1*'` works for me but it might not be doing what you expect. It removes anything containing `bonjovi_album` followed by 0 or more `1` s.  In this case it's equivalent to the pattern `bonjovi_album`.